# On Complete on Normal function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Piece of code I want to execute just after the completing the first function

```
        doc_ViewModel.encryption(img,txt,uid!!)
```

The above is just a random function [User defined]
After this function is completed I want to trigger a block of Code but I am unable to access to On Complete Or On Success Listner via user defined functions

So in short, how can I trigger a block of code after Finishing of First function and only than proceeding to the next one?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: android studio is the IDE, when in doubt, use android

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value/57330767#57330767) for reference on callbacks and async operations

Comment: In most cases the code executes sequentially, from top to bottom, so just put your code below the `encryption()` line?

Comment: Yes but that doesn't wait till enc() completes.   I did solve it by using Callbacks ty